# iOS//Provisioning Profiles//Old Data&New Data

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, provisioning-profile, savestate

I've never been using Xcode to sideload apps on my iPad instead,I used Cydia Impactor. We all knows that the limitation is every free Apple developer account comes with a 7-days provisioning profile. In other words, after a week, you will need to repeat this process again for the app to work. I got this app which is not available anymore in app store and this app I've been playing consists savedata,etc. So,my question is how do I renew/refresh/re-play/(you name it)  the same app/game without deleting the old data but conserving/save the old data? Because,after a week I've been playing in that game,I feel sad when the app crashed,,urgh,I really hope that Apple at least return back the 1 year provisioning profile... PLease help me

## FOCUS

1-Example,I downloaded the app 1/1/2016

2- A week later 8/1/2016 (it turns to old data)

3- IF let say,on 9 or 10/1/2016 (new data),,,how do I keep the old savesdata from the old provisioning profile dated (1/1/2016)?

aid me please :(

Comment: Can we see the code snippet? stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: Even if it's not available in the app store, you should still be able to download it again if you bought it.

Comment: You guys understood my question in the wrong way.. nvm though ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer app data into / out of an app using the Xcode devices window. Depending on how the app stores the data, that may work, or it may not.  Apple hasn't done anything with the 1 year provisioning profile - it still requires a valid paid developer account.  If you want full development capabilities, sign up for an account.

Reinstalling an app that has a new provisioning profile won't delete the app data, though. In reality, you should be able to simply update the provisioning profile on the device and the existing app will run.  The problem is that the free account doesn't let you do manual profile maintenance, so there really isn't a good way to do this with the free account.  Simply build over the existing app without deleting the app first and you should be fine.  If you are worried, you could do a device backup first and restore if something goes wrong.  Unless you provide more details / code, it's going to be tough for you to get help.

Comment: Thank you all... I just found out that the problem I was facing is just to repeat the same method how I installed the app A.K.A. resigning/renewing the provisioning profile. ^_^